# HELP I want a REFUND for my ethereum that has been sent

Tags: transactions, blockchain, contract-deployment, myetherwallet, etherscan

[image]Yesterday I sent token and made a contract with Live edu ICO from MEW with an amount of 16.35+ ETH, the transaction status is success but the tokens was not shown in ICO due to the finished contribution that I didn't knew when I send my money. I need to cancel this transaction now.

Comment: If transaction status is success, you cannot revet it. Add tx hash to your question.

Comment: Read about blockchain: What is done is done. If you are not able to even verify dates, you should stop use cryptos ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are final, but I don't think anything went wrong here.

[The transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcee27a9c5bb2f33654ee1cd065560f80c3939ea148a29b5bf8ce6d6339ad8246) went to [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2097175d0abb8258f2468e3487f8db776e29d076#code). There's nothing in the contract code that sends tokens when you contribute.

I believe that makes sense given this quote from https://tokensale.liveedu.tv/en/buy-tokens/how-to-buy-edu-tokens:

> All EDU tokens will be distributed after closing of the public ICO. More information on receiving tokens will be provided later on this site.